# Guardar imagen en una ruta especifica en visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

Buen día. Tengo el siguiente problema: Cuando selecciono la imagen y le doy **aceptar**, me arroja el siguiente error: `A generic error occurred en GDI+.`

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Public Sub CargarImagen(ByVal OPF As OpenFileDialog, ByVal PB As PictureBox)

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection 'conexion con la base de datos
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand 'sentencia sql a utilizar
    Dim pa As New SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 50) 'parametro de la sentencia sql
    Dim data() As Byte 'arreglo de bytes el cual contedra la imagen
    Dim ios As FileStream 'Manejo de archivos

    Try
        OPF.Filter = "Imagenes (JPG)|*.jpg" 'filtro de archivos del OpenFileDialog 
        If OPF.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then ' en caso de que se aplaste el boton cancelar salga y no haga nada
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ios = New FileStream(OPF.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) 'instanciamos en Stream indicandole la ruta del arvhivo,el modo de acceso y si es de lectura o escritura
            ReDim data(ios.Length) 'llenamos el arreglo
            ios.Read(data, 0, CInt(ios.Length)) 'llenamos el arreglo
            PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage 'establecemos como se visualiza la imagen
            PB.Load(OPF.FileName) 'visualizamos abriendo el archivo seleccionado

            pa.Value = data 'llenamos la variable parametro con el arreglo
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Imagen values('" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & "',@data)" ' realizacion la sentencia sql respectiva
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_FA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=f5;Password=f5report" 'establecemos conexion con la base de datos
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pa) 'agregamos el parametro a la sentencia
            conn.Open() 'abrimos la conexion
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'ejecutamos la sentencia
            conn.Close() 'cerramos la conexion
            Dim ImagesDirectory As String = Path.Combine("C:\FormularioFA\Fotos", "" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & "")

            Dim folder As String = Path.Combine(ImagesDirectory, "C:\FormularioFA\Fotos")
            ' Si no existe la carpeta, la creamos
            If (Not Directory.Exists(folder)) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)
            End If
            Dim rutaImagen As String = Path.Combine(ImagesDirectory, "" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".jpg")
            PB.Image.Save("C:\FormularioFA\Fotos\" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification) 'en caso de error muestre un mensaje
    End Try
End Sub
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Podrias aclarar en que linea sale el error?

Comment: Elimina el `Try/Catch` temporalmente y dinos en que línea salta el error

Comment: El error sale en la siguiente linea:  PB.Image.Save("C:\FormularioFA\Fotos\" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion:

```
       Public Sub CargarImagen(ByVal OPF As OpenFileDialog, ByVal PB As PictureBox)
       Dim conn As New SqlConnection 'conexion con la base de datos
       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand 'sentencia sql a utilizar
       Dim pa As New SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 50) 'parametro de la 
       sentencia sql
       Dim data() As Byte 'arreglo de bytes el cual contedra la imagen
       Dim ios As FileStream 'Manejo de archivos
        Try

        OPF.Filter = "Imagenes (JPG)|*.jpg" 'filtro de archivos del OpenFileDialog 
        If OPF.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then ' en caso de que se aplaste el boton cancelar salga y no haga nada
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ios = New FileStream(OPF.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) 'instanciamos en Stream indicandole la ruta del arvhivo,el modo de acceso y si es de lectura o escritura
            ReDim data(ios.Length) 'llenamos el arreglo
            ios.Read(data, 0, CInt(ios.Length)) 'llenamos el arreglo
            PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage 'establecemos como se visualiza la imagen
            PB.Load(OPF.FileName) 'visualizamos abriendo el archivo seleccionado

            pa.Value = data 'llenamos la variable parametro con el arreglo
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Imagen values('" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & "',@data)" ' realizacion la sentencia sql respectiva
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_FA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=f5;Password=f5report" 'establecemos conexion con la base de datos
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pa) 'agregamos el parametro a la sentencia
            conn.Open() 'abrimos la conexion
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'ejecutamos la sentencia
            conn.Close() 'cerramos la conexion
        'Dim ImagesDirectory As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "C:\FormularioFA\Fotos\")

        Dim folder As String = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\FormularioFA\Fotos")
        ' Si no existe la carpeta, la creamos
        If (Not Directory.Exists(folder)) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)
            End If
        Dim rutaImagen As String = Path.Combine(folder, "" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".jpg")
        File.Copy(OPF.FileName, "C:\FormularioFA\Fotos\" & My.Forms.Formulario_FA.Assembly_SerialNumber.Text & ".jpg")
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Cuál es la solución?, revisar [answer].